# When I am moving the left hand bone (right and left hand both moving) because I made my character using the Mirror modifier

Tags: rigging, mirror, pose-mode

You can see when I am moving left hand the bone right hand is also moving. But when I am moving right hand bone nothing happens. It is because I used the *Mirror* modifier for making this character. If any one knows how to solve the thing problem then please let me know.

Why is the right hand also moving with the left hand bone?

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

[image]

Comment: when i move right hand   bone the character hand  is not moving with bone but with left hand bone both right and left hand is moving  can any one know the solution please tell (i made the character using mirror modifier )

Comment: Maybe in your modifier stack put the Mirror modifier above the Armature?

Comment: THANKS FOR SUGGESTION BUT STILL NOT WORKING

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: FILE SEND DONE PLESE CHECK

Comment: you have to copy the link you get from blend-exchange to your question

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/Q8RmE8J1

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Q8RmE8J1" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Q8RmE8J1/)

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work, you could apply the Mirror but it doesn't answer why it doesn't work

Comment: it is happening every time i create because of this issue i cannot rig a character properly .

Comment: but i find one temporary solution for this  first(in edit mode) delete only  those bone which are not working properly then (in object mode) select object and then press ctrl +A  and apply (scale) then select armature press ctrl+a  and apply (scale) then go to (edit mode) create those bones which are deleted previously  and then (object mode) press on object and then Armature  and(ctrl +p) apply automatic weight again  some time it works and some time it not if any one can give permanent solution then it will be very helpful  (if any one facing same issue you can try this method  for temporar)